# Checkbox alignment issues within PHP/HTML form

Tags: php, html, css, checkbox

I am trying to edit a form I have used many times but now I need to add checkboxes for options and I cannot for the life of me get them to align correctly or figure out where the formatting needs to be changed. I am not an expert at PHP, HTML, or CSS I was just tasked with this being in IT so I am learning as I am going. You guys have always came to my rescue on previous projects too and I am about a days worth deep into it with no changes. Made the checkboxes red in the CSS just so I could make sure a change I made to them went.

Basically want the checkboxes to look like this:

**Project needs:  [] Photography         [] Videography       [] Resize**

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Marketing and Communications Request</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="marketing_style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<center>
    <br /><br /><img src="logo.jpg" width="350px" height"100px"><br /><br />
    <H1>Marketing and Communications Request</H1>
</center>


    <div id="page-wrap">
        <div id="contact-area">
            
            
            <br />
            <br />
            <form method="post" action="marketing_contactengine.php">
                <label for="Name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
                
                <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />

                <label for="Phone">Phone:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone" />

                <label for="Dept">Department:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Dept" id="Dept" />
                
                <label for="Dir">Department Director:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Dir" id="Dir" />       
                
                <label for="COID">COID/Account Code (GL Code):</label>
                <input type="text" name="COID" id="COID" />     
                
<br><br>
<br><br>
    <h2><u>EVENT INFORMATION</u></h2>
                <label for="EventName">Event Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="EventName" id="EventName" />           
                
                <label for="EventDateTime">Event Date & Time:</label>
                <input type="text" name="EventDateTime" id="EventDateTime" placeholder="01/01/2021 08:00:00" />                 
                
                <label for="EventLocation">Event Location:</label>
                <input type="text" name="EventLocation" id="EventLocation" />       
                
                <label for="Desc">Brief description of the event:</label><br />
                <textarea name="Desc" rows="2" cols="10" id="Desc"></textarea>  

<br><br>
<br><br>
    <h2><u>PROJECT INFORMATION</u></h2>
                <label for="ProjectName">Project Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="ProjectName" id="ProjectName" />

                <label for="Materials">Materials due date:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Materials" id="Materials" />
<br />

</div>

<div id="checkboxes" class="checkboxes">
<label id="ProjectNeeds" for="ProjectNeeds" class="checkboxes">Project needs (check all that apply):</label>


<label class="checkboxes" for="Photography"><input type="checkbox" id="Photography" /> <span>Photography</span></label>
<label class="checkboxes" for="Videography"><input type="checkbox" id="Videography" /> <span>Videography</span></label>
<label class="checkboxes" for="Resize"><input type="checkbox" id="Resize" /> <span>Resize</span></label>

 </div>
</div>



</div>


    <div id="bottom"  style="position: relative;">    
    <div style="position: absolute;">
    Submission of this form is required for all requests to the marketing and communications team.
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

}

#page-wrap {
    background: white;
    padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
    min-height: 500px;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 500px;
    width: 700px;
}

#contact-area {
    width: 660px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    
}

#contact-area input, #contact-area textarea {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 471px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    /* border: 2px solid #ccc; */
}

/* #contact-area textarea { */
/*  height: 90px; */
/* } */

#contact-area textarea:focus, #contact-area input:focus {
    border: 2px solid #900;

}

#contact-area input.submit-button {
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}

label {
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
}




#bottom {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 100px;
    width: 900px;
    padding-top: 75px;
    padding-bottom: 75px; 
    text-align: left;
}



#checkboxes {
    color: red;

}
```

Comment: Your `<label>`s all have a width of 100px, that's why text inside it floats to a new line. Set `width: inherit` for your "red" ones

Comment: Perfect! I knew it was something easy I was just overlooking. Thanks so much for the quick response.

Comment: And ... `height"100px"` is missing a `=`, your `<form>` never gets closed, there are superfluous `</div>`s in your form, `<center>` is obsolete and should not be used. Maybe replace your `<br>` with separator divs with a certain height

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, you have a `label {}` declaration that is affecting all labels, including the ones next to your input radios. It is making them float and that's why they mess up.

To fix it you need to add another declaration that cancels the float for the labels inside #checkboxes, like so:

```
  #checkboxes label {
    float: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the label CSS properties like that:

```
label {
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And add another CSS line:

```
.checkboxes input { float:left; vertical-align:middle; margin-right:10px; }
```